# Manually call cascade delete?

Tags: mysql, cascading-deletes

Let's say I have 3 tables, "child1", "child2" and "child3", that all have a foreign key to the table "parent".
Table "parent" got a field "status", and I would that if status is set to "0" for an element, all its child are deleted. (I use trigger to detect status changes).
So it's like calling "cascade delete", but without deleting the object ...

Is there a good way to do this ?

Comment: So if I understand, you intend to cause all FK related children to be deleted without actually deleting the parent row?

Comment: If you're using Triggers, you're already very likely implementing pretty bad practices (and performance will suffer).

Comment: @Romain I respectfully disagree that triggers = bad practice. In fact, this question sounds like a valid use case for a trigger which would delete the child rows when the parent status changes.

Comment: @JoeStefanelli I'm not saying `triggers = bad practice`, but rather `triggers = often bad practice symptom`. There are definitely valid cases for triggers, and this may be one, however this doesn't generally scale up (but it depends on your scalability needs I suppose).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trigger detects the change, you need to use it to fire a stored procedure. Here's a good tutorial: http://markalexanderbain.suite101.com/mysql-stored-procedures-and-triggers-a71091

Alternatively if you are using php, coldfusion or some other middle tier, you could read the record into a variable. Do delete the row, then re-insert the record. But you are better off with the stored procedure doing the work.

Comment: The question is not about trigger or procedure, but a way to do a cascade delete without delete the parent !

Comment: You would need to do it with a stored procedure. You already have the trigger, write a stored procedure to delete the records in the children tables and fire it from you're trigger. If you're asking if you can just do the cascade directly without deleting the parent then the answer is that you cannot.

Answer (score 0):

delete all children with associated foreign key to the parent..

```
authorname = Bill, authorid = 5
```

we need to delete all books by bill

```
DELETE FROM books WHERE authorid=5
```

EDIT: sorry, re-read.. you could implement this logic on `UPDATE` of the status