# How to Cascade on Delete Manually

Tags: mysql

I have a table for example called `Updates`

```
Update_ID | Time
```

and another table called `Announce_Updates`

```
Announce_ID | Update_ID
```

They all have cascade on delete but i can think of some moments when I switched off foreign key check and forgot to reactivate. During that moment, I may have deleted some data on the `Updates` table which didn't auto delete on the `Announce_Updates` table.

I realized something was wrong when the total count of `Update_ID` in `Announce_Updates` is greater than that of the main `Updates` table itself.

Is there a way to fix this ?

Best regards.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7663724/manually-call-cascade-delete

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If there are orphaned `Announce_Updates` records you can delete any which don't have a matching `Update`:

```
DELETE FROM Announce_Updates WHERE Update_ID NOT IN (SELECT Update_ID FROM Updates)
```

As always make sure you back up the database before running any queries that some guy on the internet told you to.